# Click specific div element that is closest to my span tag

Tags: jquery

I wrote a function that returns 4 different span elements from a multiple choice.  I then wrote another function that selects the answer.

I'm not sure how I can hook these two pieces up together.

Here are the spans that are returned

```
<span class="choice-label" data-bind=​"text:​ fact.value">​Randy Thompson</span>​
<span class=​"choice-label" data-bind=​"text:​ fact.value">​Colton Roberts​</span>​
<span class=​"choice-label" data-bind=​"text:​ fact.value">​Eric Stavers​</span>​
<span class=​"choice-label" data-bind=​"text:​ fact.value">​Jessica Linglong​</span>​
```

My other functions returns the first name only, so for example '`eric`'

Each span above is surrounded by a div with a `btn btn-class`.

How do I pick out only the span that matches 'eric'.

Here is the function that grabs the name to be later used

```
var s = $("div.card-content[data-bind='resizedImage: questionFact.value']").css('background-image');
var n = s.indexOf('-');
s = s.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
s.replace('url("http://mytestsite.com/testcase/', '');

s == eric
```

So from s I need to click on the span above but the closest div with a class of `btn btn-class`

Here is what I use to pull out the 4 different​ spans.  `$('div .answer span')`

I've tried $('div .answer span:contains(eric)') but that doesn't work.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try `$("div .answer span:contains('eric')")` you'r misssing quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try $("div .answer span:contains('Eric')") (contains is case sensitive)

Comment: Is there a way to turn my eric into camel case with jquery?  My answer finder function returns the answer in all lower case, original hidden answer is also in lower case as well.

Comment: There's no built in jquery function to do that but a quick search on here should give you functions to do that using regex.